# Understanding Android Canvas Clipping

Tags: android, android-canvas, clipping

I am having trouble finding an answer to this.  Consider the clipping code below:

```
           boolean is_ok = mycanvas.clipRect(clip_left, clip_top, clip_right+1, clip_bottom+1);
       mycanvas.getClipBounds(clipRect);
       if (!is_ok ||
               clipRect.left != clip_left ||
               clipRect.top != clip_top ||
               clipRect.right != clip_right+1 ||
               clipRect.bottom != clip_bottom+1)
       {
           Log.i("DEBUG", "setClipping failed");
       }
```

When the clip bounds are returned they don't match what was just set.  For example if clip_left, clip_top, clip_right, clip_bottom are (100,50,109, 59) then I would expect the clipping bounds to be (100, 50, 110, 60) given the code above.  It isn't.  getClipBounds() returns (100, 51, 110, 60).

Why is top = 51 when I just set it to 50?  There's something under the hood I don't understand yet.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this is under Android 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I need to read more clearly before asking questions.  In case anyone is interested I'll answer this myself:

When setting a new clipRect, I assumed it would replace the prior clipping.  This is NOT so.  Instead it creates an intersection with the previous clipping.  From the Android Developers page:

> clipRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
>
> Intersect the current clip with the specified rectangle, which is
>   expressed in local coordinates.

Comment: To replace prior clipping, the proper code would be:  boolean is_ok = mycanvas.clipRect(clip_left, clip_top, clip_right+1, clip_bottom+1, Region.Op.REPLACE);